# The length of a line segment related to a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, quadrilateral

> In parallelogram $ABCD$, angle $A$ is acute, point $E$ is on the $AD$ such that $BE$ is perpendicular to $AD$ and point $F$ is on line $CD$ such that $BF$ is perpendicular to $CD$. If $AB=BF=13$ and $AE=5$, compute the length of $EF$.

I drew the diagram, all I can do is to get the length of $BE$ by Pythagorean theorem, I'm learning geometry (sophomore), does this question require knowledge about calculus or trig?  Can anyone help me with it?

This question is from senior A division contest.

Comment: Geometry ---specifically, similar triangles--- will get you where you need to go. You know that $\triangle AEB$ is a $5$-$12$-$13$ triangle. Let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to $AB$; and let $Q$ be on $BC$ such that $EQ\parallel AB$; finally, let $R$ be the point where $EQ$ meets $BF$. Now ... $\triangle APE \sim AEB$, and you know $|AE|$, so proportionality gives you $|AP|$ and $|PE|$. Thus, you also know $|RQ|$ and $|BR|$. (Why?) These, in turn, give you $|ER|$ and $|FR|$, which are legs of a right triangle with hypotenuse $EF$.

Answer (score 1):

There's another method than what Blue said in the comments (sorry!) but involves knowledge of basic trigonometry.

[image]

By the Pythagorean Theorem, we have $BE=12$. We can find $\angle BAE$ using any of the trigonometric ratios (I'll use $\tan$):
$$\tan\angle BAE=\frac{12}{5}\Rightarrow \angle BAE \approx 67.38^\circ$$
Now, since $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, we have $\angle BCF=67.38^\circ$ also.

Next, we have to find $\angle EBF$. We know that

$$\angle EBF = \angle ABC - (\angle ABE+\angle CBF)=\angle ABC - 2\angle ABE$$

$\angle ABC=180-\angle BAE=112.62^\circ$ since adjacent angles in a parallelogram must add up to $180^\circ$. $\angle ABE = 90 - \angle BAE=22.62^\circ$ since the acute angles in a right triangle must sum to $90^\circ$. Hence, we have

$$\angle EBF=112.62-2(22.62)=67.38^\circ$$

Finally, we can use the cosine law to find $EF$. We have:

$$EF=\sqrt{12^2+13^2-2\times 12\times 13\times \cos67.38}$$
$$=\sqrt{193}$$